# What are some of the best chess opening moves, for white and black?

Tags: opening, strategy

I am wondering the best opening moves are for both white and black, because I have won games with the pawn move 1. d2-d4.

Comment: This is as factual as most questions here and I had a full answer ready to post when the nitpickers killed the ability to post it first.

Comment: Hasn't this question been done before?

The best opening move is unknown.  We can merely say that some moves seem to be SLIGHTLY better than others but that is statistical based on actual game results. 

Statistically the better moves are 
Nh3  - go figure  -  68% point average where win=1 draw=0.5 loss=0
e4                   54  more popular than d4  by 15% more usage 
Nf3                  55+
d4                   55
c4
g3
b3
f4
Nc3
b4
b3
d3
a3
c3
g3
h3
h4   formatting lost in commenting show okay in answer blocked

Comment: I don't agree that this is opinion at all, but it is WAY too broad.

Comment: @yobamamama You basically inserted your answer into the question with your edit. What you wrote would work well as a comment.

Comment: @PhishMaster  way too broad for you.  maybe just right for the noobie who asked?

Comment: @InertialIgnorance  it was no more opinion than so many other questions here.  that might work in other stacks but of lot of chess is merely opinion and cannot be proven.

Comment: @yobamamama I'm not saying what you wrote was bad, just that it would work well as a comment. When you edit a question it's best to stick to what the OP was asking, and just to make it clearer if needed.

Comment: After some consideration, I agree with PhishMaster's assessment that the question is rather too broad than opinion-based. There is just too much ground to cover in a single answer.

Comment: I think this is not too broad at all. Of course the question can be considered opinion-based, but that applies to many questions. It should simply be answered based on the opinion of renowned chess teachers. For white, 1. d4 and 1. e4 are considered best, although c4, Nf3, etc are also fine and there are good reasons to choose them. There is no first move for white that loses immediately in regular chess. After 1. d4 black should play either d5 or Nf6. After 1. e4, black has e5 or - supririsingly - c5. Black also has some good alternatives (1. d4 f5) but others are simply bad (1. e4 f5??)

Comment: Welcome Chess Newbie sorry you’ve had to go through the distressing experience of seeing your question blocked. They’re an odd lot here sometimes but they mean well. This is a fairly objective and not too broad question as can be seen by looking at chess.com opening database, which will give the relative winning rates of any opening series of moves. Hope we manage to reopen the question in which can we can give you some proper objective answers. Thanks for your patience

Comment: Question cannot be answered until chess is solved. Db stats have fatal flaws. Start with 1.d4, then you lose all of the 1. Nf3 games that transpose in. If a line that was good is suddenly refuted, you have a db with 1000 positive results and 5 negative ones. Numbers look good; line still loses. Any discussion centered around the question as written is rife with guesswork and pseudo-science.

Comment: If this is reopened, I'll vote to re-close it, because it's too unfocused. The OP doesn't provide any direction on how to answer it. "I have won games with 1. d4". Yeah, and I've won games with 1. e4, 1. c4, 1. Nf3, etc. What's there to answer?